# Manually click a child link (and navigate) when clicking parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Desired behavior - if you click anywhere on ".card" other than a "button", navigate to the link. I am not using window.location because I want users to be able to use their own discretion on whether they want a new tab, window, or just to navigate.

Actual behavior - link is not navigated to, but I get the following console output (pasted below):

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <button>Action</button>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <a href="/i/399doglsk" class="public-id"></a>
  <button>Another Action</button>
  <div class="some-more-content"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.card').on('click', function() {
  console.log('.card');
  if ($(e.target).is('button')) {
    $(this).find('a.public-id').click();
  }
});

$('body').on('click', "a.public-id", function(e) {
  console.log('a.public-id');  
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Console output:

```
card
card
a.public-id
```

Comment: @Taplar - thanks, fixed. That was a typo.

Comment: Since you also use `e` as `events` object, you should pass it as parameter => `$('.card').on('click', function(e) {});`

Comment: Shouldn't the if condition be `if (!$(e.target).is('button'))`?

Comment: @zallarak [Here's a possible solution](http://jsfiddle.net/y54sa4ua/).

Comment: @Ted Thats not a solution, you are modifying the OPs html markup

Comment: @taxicala it achieves the OP's desired result, so it _is_ a possible solution.

Comment: @Ted Maybe, but I dont see anywhere where the OP's states that the HTML markup is mutable.